# Changing IP address via command line on Windows XP

Tags: command-line, windows-xp, ip, netsh

I'm trying to change a machine IP address via cmd.exe with this code:

```
netsh int ip set address name="Local Area Connection" source=static addr=???.???.???.??? mask=255.255.255.0
```

The problem that the IP doesn't change (checked by `ipconfig`) but doesn't not changed on the DHCP. Thus when I restart the machine, the IP is returned to DHCP.

I need a way to change the IP permanently via command line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify logic in the part below `netsh` code.

Answer (score 20):

You can use the command below:

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.100 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1
```

where

- the `192.168.0.100` is the IP address
- the netmask is `255.255.255.0`
- and the gateway is `192.168.0.1`

You can also have the DNS configured automatically by DHCP using following command:

```
netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" dhcp
```

Comment: use `ipconfig` to list the gateway and netmask

Comment: i get  The requested operation requires elevation

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for change it regularly here is a trick :)

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Wi-Fi" static 192.168.1.140 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1 // this change IP
netsh interface ip add dns name="Wi-Fi" 8.8.8.8 index=2 //this change DNS
pause
```

type above in notepad and save as `ip.bat`.
run the file as administrator

Comment: This one actually works if you set the address name=“Wi-Fi” instead of “Local Area Connection”.