# Windows XP - Configure static IP address with netsh

Tags: command-line-interface, netsh, windows-xp-sp3

I am having trouble executing the following command on Windows XP SP3.

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection 2" static 192.168.100.5 255.255.255.0 192.168.100.1
```

I am fairly confident that this command is correct, however I am receiving:

```
The syntax supplied for this command is not valid.  Check help for the correct syntax.
```

This command works on Windows 7 just fine, and according to the help provided by Windows XP, this is the correct syntax.

Any one have any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868045/changing-ip-address-via-command-line-on-windows-xp/9891452

Answer (score 1):

The pc is Windows XP SP3.

I get the same error with this (Italian) interface name :

> "Connessione alla rete locale (LAN) 3"

I found the problem.

It is mandatory to specify after the gateway also the parameter gwmetric.

This solves all my issues with NETSH int ip set address.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static 1.2.3.4 255.255.255.0 2.3.4.5 gwmetric=1
```

Static IP Address ----- Subnet Mask ----- Default Gateway ------ Metric