# Get Network Interface Names and Set All to DHCP Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, dhcp, netsh

I am trying to make a batch that will get all of the Network Interface names (ex. 'Local Area Connection', 'Local Area Connection 2') and set them to DHCP.

**This is what I have so far**:

```
set netsh=wmic nic where "netconnectionid like '%%'" get netconnectionid

for %%i in ("%netsh% | FIND /V 'Net'") do (netsh interface ip set address "%%i" dhcp)
```

**My output is**:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Can anyone assist me in fixing this script, or proposing a better way to go about this please?

Answer (score 2):

Will this do what you need?

```bat
WMIC NICConfig Where "IPEnabled='True' And DHCPEnabled='False'" Call EnableDHCP
```